# How do I communicate backend errors to frontend in web development?

Tags: python, error-handling, frontend, backend, registration

I'm new to web development, so I'm just curious about the best way to communicate backend errors to the frontend? For example, I'm creating a registration form (image below), which returns an error if a user attempts to register an account with an email that already exists.

From a design perspective, I'd like to create a notification for the user regarding the error (similar to the Goodreads example below). From the backend, I know I can redirect the user to a separate, identical looking page with the notification element above the form (or a different page altogether which communicates the error), but that feels repetitious.

I'm just curious if there's something I can do where you define the error in the backend, and then the frontend knows to trigger an on-screen element if that error occurs.

```
@app.route("/register", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def register():
    if request.method == "POST":

        #Define and capture variables
        fname = request.form.get("fname")
        lname = request.form.get("lname")
        email = request.form.get("email")
        pw = request.form.get("pw")
        cpw = request.form.get("cpw")
        print(fname, lname, email, pw, cpw)

        if (not fname or not lname or not email or not pw or not cpw) or (pw != cpw):
            return("ERROR: Email already exists")
     
        pw = generate_password_hash(pw)

        try:
            db.execute('INSERT INTO users (fname, lname, email, hashpw, confirmed) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)',(fname, lname, email, pw, False))
            conn.commit()
        except:
            print("error")
            

        return render_template('register.html')
    else:
        return render_template('register.html')
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: You'd pass in an additional argument to `render_template('register.html')`, which'll make that error message appear in the template you're returning.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using Flask, so I recommend using [Flask-WTForms](https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/1.1.x/) (which is built on top of [WTForms](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/3.0.x/)) to create, validate, and generate error messages for your forms.

Then, you can use AJAX ([with jQuery](https://api.jquery.com/Jquery.ajax/)) to make requests to the backend, get the errors, and display them without reloading the page or redirecting the user.

The implementation of it depends on your code so far (frontend and backend), so I cannot show you how to proceed, but I think that this is a very good way of achieving your goal. You can find several tutorials on the internet on how to use these two "tools"